# Identify items in a character vector with duplicate letters

Tags: string, r, cpu-word, character

I have a character vector:

```
"aback" "docks" "trims"
```

I want to identify the items in this vector with unique (no duplicate) letters.  i.e.

```
FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

What is an efficient way to do this in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sapply( strsplit(c("aback", "docks", "trims"), ""), length) == 
   sapply( sapply( strsplit(c("aback", "docks", "trims"), ""), unique), length)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

# Or 
nchar(c("aback", "docks", "trims") ) == 
    sapply( sapply( strsplit(c("aback", "docks", "trims"), ""), unique), length)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(CHAR_VEC, split=""), anyDuplicated) > 0` -- where `CHAR_VEC <- rep(c("aback", "docks", "trims"), 100000)` -- looks to be nearly 2 times faster than either of these.  **If** speed were an issue, I wonder what further speed-ups would be possible in base R.

Comment: Thanks for that. Makes sense that it it is quicker snce you only process the argument once. I had not seen that function before. I checked to see if I could learn any further tricks from the code but `anyDuplicated.default` is a .Internal function